# Is there any infinite set which is Dedekind finite and weakly Dedekind finite?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

1. Is there any infinite set which is Dedekind finite and weakly Dedekind finite?
2. If $X$ is a weakly Dedekind finite amorphous set, can we show that $\mathcal P(X)$, the power set of $X$, is also weakly Dedekind finite?

If someone know, please tell (or hint) them.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please add the definitions of these concepts? Also, there seem to be some spelling errors

Answer (score 6):

Recall Kuratowski's theorem:

> $X$ can be mapped onto $\omega$ if and only if there is an injection from $\omega$ into $\mathcal P(X)$.

And also, recall that:

> $X$ is infinite if and only if $\mathcal P(X)$ can be mapped onto $\omega$.

So to answer the first question, in Cohen's first model every infinite set can be mapped onto $\omega$, so there are no infinite weakly Dedekind finite sets; on the other hand, if $A$ is amorphous, then $A$ cannot be mapped onto $\omega$, therefore its power set is Dedekind finite.

The second question follows easily from the second quoted statement.

Comment: Oh, you made my day. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Sorry, but i want to know whether P(X) is "weakly"  Dedekind finite or not, not Dedekind finite.

Comment: Weakly Dedekind finite sets, if my memory serves me right (and you provided no definition) are Dedekind finite sets that cannot be mapped onto $\omega$.

Comment: In my class,  a set X is weakly Dedekind finite if there is no surjection from X onto $/omega$.

Comment: Yes, as I wrote. And as I wrote in my answer, if $X$ is infinite (Dedekind finite or not), then $\mathcal P(X)$ can be mapped onto $\omega$.

Comment: You mean that "an amorphous set, in Cohen's first model, is infinite & Dedekind finite & weakly Dedekind finite", right?

Comment: No. An amorphous set is always weakly Dedekind finite; but in Cohen's first model there are no infinite weakly Dedekind finite sets.

Comment: OK. But in the second question, is power set of X is weakly Dedekind infinite? (In my class, amorphous means cannot be decomposed into two infinite set.)

Comment: I just answered that two comments ago.